# After deploy Google App Engine returns HTTP response code 403

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-app-engine, gcloud

I've done another deploys and all was fine, but after finishing the app, I'm getting this error. And the page request keeps loading.
Do I need to configure something in "IAM"?

Java 11
Standard Environment
h2 DB
Spring boot

The stack trace from Google Cloud:

> java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://clouddebugger.googleapis.com/v2/controller/debuggees/register at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1919) at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1515) at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
>   at com.google.devtools.cdbg.debuglets.java.GcpHubClient.registerDebuggee (Unknown Source)

I've got new data using Stackdriver debug.

> "message": "Stackdriver Debugger API has not been used in project
>   929024293238 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting
>   https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/clouddebugger.googleapis.com/overview?project=929024293238
>   then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for
>   the action to propagate to our systems and retry.",

Comment: Concerning the 2nd Error message you provided, have you already enabled the Stackdriver Debugging API? If not, then by following [these steps](https://cloud.google.com/debugger/docs/setup/java) you can enable it.

Comment: Yes, it's enabled. I've tried disabling, enabling and waiting too.

Answer (score 3):

Just a note if somebody else stumbles across this error: I had the same message in Google's App Engine dashboard popping up up to 60 times in a couple of minutes.

Enabling the Stackdriver Debugging API, as linked above, solved it. No more error logs (of that kind) were being produced. The weired thing is that the Stackdriver Debugging API should have been turned on by default for my standard environment.

Comment: Hi Dirk, it's great that you want to contribute and help other people! Please consider changing your answer into a comment. Here is a post that may be helpful to decide: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297066/meta-meta-stack-overflow-when-should-i-answer-or-comment

Comment: @Stefan Yeah, I'd love to, but I have to have a higher reputation score to add comments (50). Adding an answer was the only way stackoverflow gave me to leave a note (I think).

Comment: I enabled cloud debugging api and error is no more popping up

Comment: I had the same issue myself -- tens of thousands of these error messages per day cluttering the dashboard. Enabling the debugging API (now called Cloud Debugger rather than Stackdriver) solved the issue; thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The log wasn't very informative.
I change the application port from 8000 to 8080.

application.properties:
server.port=${PORT:8080}

Now the app is running fine.

Answer (score 0):

Dec 2023 here.
I found an [article](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/deprecations/debugger-deprecation) in Google Cloud Operations Suite docs saying that:

> Cloud Debugger was deprecated on May 16, 2022 and the service was shut down on May 31, 2023.

As I couldn't find a way to enable Cloud Debugger as suggested in the solutions above, I had to guess something else.

In my case, I found that one of the old versions of our application (from February 2023) had 1 instance running (with 0% traffic) along with a current version which had 100% of the traffic.

I **stopped the old version** and since then I haven't seen those errors anymore.