# After deploy Google App Engine returns HTTP response code 403 and Permission Denied error

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-iam

When I deploy my Java Spring Boot application to GAE, I keep getting this error in the logs multiple times. Following errors keep repeating after every second. All APIs in the service works perfectly but I keep getting these errors. I have already checked Stackdriver Debugging API is already enabled.

```
Using :
Java 11 ,
Spring Boot,
GAE

java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://clouddebugger.googleapis.com/v2/controller/debuggees/register at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1924) at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1520) at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250) at com.google.devtools.cdbg.debuglets.java.GcpHubClient.registerDebuggee(Unknown Source)

W0428 12:15:44.303382 30 jni_logger.cc:46] Failed to register debuggee

{"error": {"code": 403,"message": "The caller does not have permission",
"status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}}
```

Comment: Have you seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58488404/after-deploy-google-app-engine-returns-http-response-code-403). Sounds familiar, did it?

Comment: yes i tried but it didn't work for my case @vitooh

Comment: It seems that the account does not have the appropriate permission. I would suggest
making sure that the account has the ""Cloud Debugger Agent"" IAM role.
https://cloud.google.com/debugger/docs/iam